# Javascript works when tested locally but stops when uploaded

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I have created a super simple javascript calculator to help me work out a budget.

The problem is that is works fine when tested locally on my computer but the second I upload it to the correct directory, it ceases to function.

Here is a jsbin
http://jsbin.com/ijumuh/1/edit

When I upload it to www.mysite.com/test.html it works, however when I put it in the right folder www.mysite.com/directory/test.html it stops working.

Any idea what could causes this?

Comment: Please add the live preview of your site. Also, what exactly means "not working"?

Comment: The only thing that could stop working is images..

Comment: I've added the live site :)

Comment: No errors in the console? I see at least 10 warnings about not being able to load resources (JS files and images). For example it tries to load http://thatgirlnicola.com/respond.min.js which doesn't exist.

Comment: It does exist in the correct directory though - on the version that is not functioning correctly. (I see the errors on the version that is the first link - just broken images and missing js)

Comment: Well, could it be that the respond.min.js interferes with the calculator since the working version doesn't use it?

Comment: I just removed it from the page and deleted it from directory - still no difference. That's the sort of thinking I need though!

Comment: You should use the jQuery event handlers, not inline handlers like `onclick="fadd()"`. You also use globally-scoped variables, which could be interfering with something or vice versa.

Comment: Actually, it's something that jQuery mobile does. It works if you click on the button's far left side. (The actual button is there, the rest of it is just a mockup.) Using jQuery event handlers might help.

Comment: Nice spotting! Thanks a lot. I'll get to sorting that out.

Comment: You might want to fix your English too! "You might be surprised on how quickly you're money dissapears."

Comment: @NicolaConeelee - Here is a fully jQuery'd version, including recalc on keypress: http://jsfiddle.net/WjBfu/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WjBfu/1 (Slightly improved edit using checkbox for week.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your input buttons(`#btnadd, #btnmult`) have a fixed width of `80px` in `styles.css` so the onclick event handler will only work if you click the leftmost area of the buttons. Remove lines 85-91 and your buttons will work again.